# Xamarin Forms AdMob trouble with AudioManager

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

When i get request from admob, every millisecond my debug console spamming me:
D/AudioManager (26589): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0. 

I don't have any single line of code about sound. Ad(banner) is showing but this affects on the performance. Anyone have this problem? 
I tried a lot of samples like this: 
https://startdebugging.net/how-to-add-admob-to-your-xamarin-forms-app/
https://xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/

Comment: This only happens after adding Admob?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I highly doubt it is affecting performance, if AudioManager was spamming logcat at a high enough rate, the OS would rate limit its output...)

It is telling you that an meadiation/interstitial ad wants to play some sound and the OS is replying that the channel is muted (at level 0).

Now you can request that your app is muted and that no ads be requested/played that contain an audio track:

```
Android.Gms.Ads.MobileAds.SetAppMuted(true);
```

> Note: Video ads that are ineligible to be shown with muted audio are not returned for ad requests made when the app volume is reported as muted or set to a value of 0. This may restrict a subset of the broader video ads pool from serving.

- https://developers.google.com/admob/android/global-settings

Comment: @naxbcr As I stated, it is just a "request", it could be the OEM's Android image is causing a conflict, etc... (I seem some Samsung models go "crazy" in regards to AudioManager output...). Have you tried it on other emulators/devices and other API levels?

Comment: @SushiHagover 
I tested on 22 and  27 Api, was the same. 
Debug logs: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1llbjm3xqh7ymrr/Debug.txt?dl=0
Maybe i need do something with Android Sdk Manager?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/al78kpppte03xjm/AndroidSdkManager.png?dl=0